# Unity3d collision with mesh

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I am new to Unity3D and I am pretty sure that something similar was asked before, but apparently I am not googling it right.

I am trying to solve the following problem: I have a car and a road game objects. A player can control the car in a top-down fashion. I want to detect when the car is off the road.

So, I created a mesh collider around the road in order to detect collision in `OnCollisionEnter()`:

[image]

Since the **RoadBoundry** game object does not have a rigid body component, I expect that the car would just pass through it, however it interacts with it in a weird way:

[image]

Why the car interacts with mesh that way and how to detect a collision in my case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the collider as a trigger

[image: trigger]

Then use `OnTriggerEnter` event.

---

FYI there is a more simple way, use `Physics.Raycast` to the ground, and give the path collider a special tag /or special layer.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I can not do it with Mesh Collider. As you can see on the image Is Trigger checkbox disabled.

Comment: Convex need be checked also, then you can not use a whole mesh, but split it into pieces.